# webservices in Python: lightest and most efficient solution

Tags: python, web-services, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

I decided to write in Python the webservices for my mobile app.
There will be about 10 web services, which will have to do web scraping and return JSON data.

I am trying to figure out the best solution.

I had been thinking to use NGINX+uWSGI+Flask.

But I have found out that Flask has got a few things I don't need, for example the Jinja2 templating system.

What about just using Werkzeug, which is the WSGI utility library used by Flask?
Would the server be more efficient with Werkzeug instead of the whole Flask?

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Honestly just pick a framework that looks good and go. You are over-thinking and trying to solve a problem before it presents itself.

Comment: I have already 700,000 users of that app, whose webservices were written in PHP, so I am trying to find a very efficient solution

Comment: @DanieleB If you managed to maintain an application this big in PHP it's going to be cake in any Python framework. That is not supposed to be a snarky comment, i am serious.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of options. Though, you've mentioned that there are a lot of users and you need very efficient solution.

Having this in mind, consider using [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) and [nginx](http://nginx.org/) as a load balancer, that forwards requests to your tornado servers:

> By using non-blocking network I/O, Tornado can scale to tens of
>   thousands of open connections.
>
> The framework is distinct from most mainstream web server frameworks
>   (and certainly most Python frameworks) because it is non-blocking and
>   reasonably fast. Because it is non-blocking and uses epoll or kqueue,
>   it can handle thousands of simultaneous standing connections, which
>   means the framework is ideal for real-time web services.

---

I've personally used this combination while building an online-store with mongodb as a database, communicating with it using an asynchronous python driver for tornado and mongodb, called [motor](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/). Feel free to ask any questions about this option.

Hope that helps.